# Installing software using command line silent mode

Tags: batch-file, azure, command, windows-installer, installation

I am creating batch file to run on azure worker start up task to install GPG software on windows 8 in silent mode or quiet mode -don't want to see UI dialogs

how to pass installation folder or other parameters in command line

I have tried using below line but it shows windows installer popup

```
msiexec  "c:\gpg4win-2.2.4.exe" /qn
```

and tried

```
"c:\gpg4win-2.2.4.exe"
```

I am getting windows installer UI -GPG win setup UI

Please help me how i can run installation in quite mode by passing required parameters

Comment: is `c:\gpg4win-2.2.4.exe /?` helpful?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a portable version and just xcopy deploying it? The .exe is "probably" no MSI and you should look at http://www.gpg4win.org/doc/en/gpg4win-compendium_35.html

Comment: @Stephan-c:\gpg4win-2.2.4.exe / this command aslo showing UI

Comment: @simon - i have to do it azure worker role can not do xcopy...

Comment: better fit for serverfault.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As the documentation states](http://www.gpg4win.org/doc/en/gpg4win-compendium_35.html) there are explicit switches and configuration files for your installation scenario. A simple example could be

```
gpg4win-2.2.4.exe /S /D=D:\Temp\Gpg4win
```

specifying `/S` for silent and `/D` for the destination path which might be relevant for your scenario.

If you need more detailed setting the documentation shows how to prepare a configuration file with fine grained settings.

Comment: Working ..Thanks Simon Opelt